# matplotlib redraw patch after figure clear

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to store a number of patches and redraw them after a figure clear. The minimal example below let's you

1. draw an axes with an image on click of mouse button 1
2. draw a circle patch on click of mouse button 2
3. clear the figure on click of mouse button 3

When you do it the second time the circle does not appear anymore. What do I have to do to make this happen?

PS: In real life this is all part of a complex image viewer app with switching between different layouts/number of axes. So, I really need the fig.clf(). Also, the app handles scrolling through image stacks where some images have patches and some don't. I'd really like to keep the patches to redraw them when the same image is redrawn (maybe even in a different axes) at a later time.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np

ax      = None
circle  = None
image   = None

array   = np.array([np.arange(512)/51.1,]*512)
fig     = plt.figure(facecolor='black')

def on_press(event):
    global ax, circle, image

    if event.button == 1:
        if not ax:
            ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0,0.8,1])
        image = ax.imshow(array, cmap = 'Greys')
        
    if event.button == 2:
        if not circle:
            circle = Circle( (255,255), 25, color='lightgreen', fill=None)
        if ax and not circle in ax.patches:
            ax.add_patch(circle)
            print(circle)
            print(ax.patches)
    
    if event.button == 3:
        fig.clf()
        ax = None
        if circle:
            circle.axes = None
        
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you replace `circle.axes = None` by `circle._axes = None` and `circle._transformSet = False` things seem to work.  I don't know whether that's the recommended approach.

Comment: Awesome, works for me too in the example. I'll try it out in the actual "complex image viewer app"!